# "A world-spanning empire" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> These self-satisfied cotton manufacturers and merchants had reason to be smug: They stood at the center of a **world-spanning** empire—the empire of cotton.

This is a sentence from the book *Empire of Cotton*. I looked up **world-spanning**, but it apparently doesn't exist in dictionaries. A post on WordReference suggests it possibly means *worldwide*. What does this word mean exactly? And how common is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **world-spanning** is formed by analogy so that it, and its analogues, are not always going to be found in a dictionary.  The empire is one that spans the world.

Such compounds can be pretty much coined as needed, though some are "ready made" collocations.

Compare

tree-hugging commies

earth-shattering news

mind-numbing repetition

tongue-twisting syllables

fire-extinguishing foam

itch-soothing ointment

frequency-modulating device

hair-raising adventure

back-breaking labor

spine-tingling suspense

news-dominating soundbite

mind-altering substance

thirst-quenching beverage